# SQL: Assigning a 2 row unique ID for every 2 rows of data

Tags: sql, case, uniqueidentifier

I think I worded the title a little awkwardly but here is my issue:

I have a `Sybase` table like below where every 2 rows needs to have a `unique ID` that's separate from every other 2 rows in the table. So rows 1 and 2 need an `ID` that is different from rows 3 and 4 and the rest of the table. The "Symbol" can repeat. There is always a "B" and an "S" tied to each other but no current ID to connect them. The ExecID and OrderID is not always truly sequential (ie 010001, 010002) but will be in order. I've tried a few variations of `CASE WHEN` but I can't think of anything that will do the trick.

What is the best way to do this?

```
Symbol | Sell-Buy | ExecId   | OrderId   | RowNum |
---------------------------------------------------
W      | B        | 64240624 | 101773407 | 1      |
W      | S        | 64240625 | 101773408 | 2      |
XM     | B        | 64240626 | 101773409 | 3      |
XM     | S        | 64240627 | 101773410 | 4      |
GV     | B        | 64240628 | 101773411 | 5      |
GV     | S        | 64240629 | 101773412 | 6      |

....

W      | B        | 64240679 | 101773455 | 49     |
W      | S        | 64240680 | 101773456 | 50     |
```

Goal of the output:

```
Symbol | Sell-Buy | ExecId   | OrderId   | RowNum | 2RowId |
------------------------------------------------------------
W      | B        | 64240624 | 101773407 | 1      | 000001 |
W      | S        | 64240625 | 101773408 | 2      | 000001 |
XM     | B        | 64240626 | 101773409 | 3      | 000002 |
XM     | S        | 64240627 | 101773410 | 4      | 000002 |

....

W      | B        | 64240679 | 101773455 | 49     | 000025 |
W      | S        | 64240680 | 101773456 | 50     | 000025 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick you could use here would be to take the ceiling of the current row number divided by 2:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET 2RowId = CEILING(RowNum / 2)
```

Here is a table showing how the math should work out:

```
RowNum | RowNum/2 | ceiling(RowNum/2)
1      | 0.5      | 1
2      | 1        | 1
3      | 1.5      | 2
4      | 2        | 2
...    | ...      | ...
```

Comment: Yup, there it is! Thanks! I'll mark the answer correct when the post lets me.

Comment: In American English the saying would be "whoop, there it is" :-)